# How to use Schema.org to identify header/footer links as being part of a WebPage defintion?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to utilize Microdata to help search engines define all the content of my website as it is intended to be viewed.

I have the following markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/link-to-canonical-url-of-this-page" />
</head>
<body>

    <div itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite">
        <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com" />
    </div>
    <header itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 pb-0 mt-2" itemprop="citation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
          <li>
          <a title="" itemprop="url" href="/some-uri" class="btn btn-link text-white" style="font-size: larger;">
          <strong itemprop="name">Popular Searches</strong>
          </a>
          <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
    </main>

    <footer itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPFooter">
        <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 pb-0 mt-2" itemprop="citation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
          <li>
          <a title="" itemprop="url" href="/some-uri" class="btn btn-link text-white" style="font-size: larger;">
          <strong itemprop="name">Popular Searches</strong>
          </a>
          <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I view the above in [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), it detects everything I intended except for the position of each element.

The tool detects the data as three different nodes. Since all these nodes are part of the `WebSite` or `WebPage`, I am hoping to somehow link the header and footer inside the `WebPage` node.

How can I indicate that the [`WPHeader`](https://schema.org/WPHeader) and [`WPFooter`](https://schema.org/WPFooter) are part of the [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) node?

[image]

#### Update

I found a way to combine all 3 nodes into the main `WebPage`. However, I used multiple `mainContentOfPage` or `mainEntity` to do it. I am not sure if having `mainContentOfPage` is the correct way to do it. It kinds contradict the name as there should always be a main-content of a single page.

Here is the updated HTML markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/link-to-canonical-url-of-this-page" />
</head>
<body itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
    <div itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite">
        <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com" />
    </div>
    <header itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 pb-0 mt-2" itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope="" itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
          <li>
          <a title="" itemprop="url" href="/some-uri" class="btn btn-link text-white" style="font-size: larger;">
          <strong itemprop="name">Popular Searches</strong>
          </a>
          <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
    </main>
    <footer itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPFooter">
        <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 pb-0 mt-2" itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope="" itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
          <li>
          <a title="" itemprop="url" href="/some-uri" class="btn btn-link text-white" style="font-size: larger;">
          <strong itemprop="name">Popular Searches</strong>
          </a>
          <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart) property.

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```

```html
  <div itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  </div>

  <header itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
    <nav itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    </article>
  </main>

  <footer itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
    <ul itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    </ul>
  </footer>
```

```html
</html>
```